# Desktop Bulk Upload SharePoint Profile Images

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, profile, bulk, mysite

I am looking for a tool that can bulk upload user profile images to the SharePoint My Site host. Nothing too flash, it just needs to take a directory of images named by the account name. And then set the profile field to be the uploaded image.

A key requirement is that it must be able to be run by people that do not have remote desktop access to the server. So i guess that means powershell scripts are out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to build my own component because one doesn't seem to exist

http://spc3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ProfileImageUpload